# How to get SAP User Id details from SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server

We are running SAP Application on top of SQL Server database running in windows server. Whenever there is high utilization we would use to see/check performance report that comes under SQL Studio. But we are not able to obtain the SAP User who is utilizing more CPU/Memory.

How to proceed further? Is there any query to check?

Comment: In my experience with SAP, there are usually SAP tools/monitoring that answer this question better than what SQL Server can do for you. Id recommend exploring that option (it will depend on what your SAP setup is and what applications you are using) and use SQL Server solutions as a last resort. In the case you choose SQL Server option then it should be no different than the numerous answers to this type of question that already exists.

Comment: _we are not able to obtain the SAP User who is utilizing more CPU/Memory_ so what do you see? It's possibly SAP does all operations as a single user which means that you won't be able to work thid out from the SQL back end

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.